# How many more odd divisors are there than even divisors?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, divisibility

Let $f(k)$ be the number of odd divisors of $k$ and $g(k)$ be the number of even divisors. Define $F(n) = \sum_{k \le n} f(k)$ and $G(n) = \sum_{k \le n} g(k)$. Thus $F(n)$ and $G(n)$ are the total number of odd and even divisors of natural numbers up to $n$. Experimental data show that

$$
\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{F(n)  - G(n)}{n} = \log 2
$$

**Question**: Is the above limit true?

**Motivation**: For a [different question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4415150/what-is-the-average-of-ratio-of-the-length-of-prime-periods-of-1-p?noredirect=1#comment9245192_4415150) I had written a program to find length of the period $l_p$ of $1/p$. It is known that $l_p|p-1$ so we only need to search among the divisors of $p_1$ to find the smallest divisor $d$ such that $10^d - 1$ is divisible by $p$. This computation is slow but I observed that overall the program runs much faster if we first scan through even divisors first and only if we do not find a $d$ then we search through odd. This is because about $2/3$ of the divisors of $p-1$ seems to be even. This led me to investigate the proportion of odd and even divisors among natural numbers.

**Source code:**

```
p = 1
step = target = 10^6
odd = even = 0

while True:
    d = divisors(p)
    l = len(d)
    i = 0
    while i < l:
        e = d[i]
        if e%2 == 1:
            odd = odd + 1
        else:
            even = even + 1
        i = i + 1
        
    if even > odd:
        print("Found", p, odd, even)
    
    if p >= target:
        t = odd + even
        print(p, odd, even, odd/t.n(), even/t.n(), (odd - even)/p.n())
        target = target + step
        
    p = p + 1
```

Comment: Odd numbers only have odd divisors?

Comment: If $n\equiv 2\mod 4$ , then the number of even divisors is equal to the number of odd divisors. , if $n\equiv 4\mod 8$ , $2$ out of $3$ divisors are even.

Comment: $F(n)$ is tabulated at https://oeis.org/A060831 and $G(2n)$ seems to be the same as https://oeis.org/A006218 which is just the summatory function for the divisor function. The links give asymptotic formulas for both, and it looks like your formula follows from there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not an answer, not very rigorous either, but here is some progress I made:

The number of times $1$ occurs as divisor from $1 \cdots n$ is $\lfloor \frac{n}{1} \rfloor$.

The number of times $2$ occurs as divisor from $1 \cdots n$ is $\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor$.

a.s.o

We are interested in $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\lfloor \frac{n}{1} \rfloor - \lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor + \lfloor \frac{n}{3} \rfloor + \cdots + (-1)^{n+1}\lfloor \frac{n}{n} \rfloor}{n}$$

Approximate this to $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\frac{n}{1} - \frac{n}{2} +\frac{n}{3}+ \cdots + (-1)^{n+1}\frac{n}{n}}{n}$$

Thus, it equals $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{1} - \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + \cdots + (-1)^{n+1}\frac{1}{n}$$

Using the expansion of $\ln (1 + 1)$, we know this is $\ln 2$.

I think this approximation works because $\lfloor \frac{n}{x} \rfloor$ has only $O(\sqrt{n})$ distinct values for $1 \leq x \leq n$. These values decrease rapidly and stay equal for longer ranges, so I think the subtraction balances things out in normal division too. And as $n \to \infty$, the "leftovers" become less significant. But again this is not a rigorous way of proving.

Answer (score 4):

We have the following facts:

- $f(k) = \tau(k)- [2\mid k]\ \tau(k/2)$
- $g(k) = [2\mid k]\ \tau(k/2)$
- $\sum\limits_{k\le x} \tau(k) = x \log x + (2\gamma +1) x + O(\sqrt{x})$

($\tau(k)$ is the numbers of positive divisors of $k$ and I'm using the [Iverson bracket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket))

Then
\begin{align}
F(x)-G(x) & = \sum_{k\le x} (f(k)- g(k)) = \sum_{k\le x}(\tau(k) - 2\ [2\mid k]\ \tau(k/2))\\
&= \sum_{k\le x}\tau(k) - 2 \sum_{k\le x}[2\mid k]\ \tau(k/2)\\
&= \sum_{k\le x}\tau(k) - 2 \sum_{k\le x/2}\tau(k)\\
&= x \log x+(2\gamma +1)x+O(\sqrt{x}) - 2 \left(\tfrac{x}{2} \log \tfrac{x}{2}+(2\gamma +1)\tfrac{x}{2}+O(\sqrt{\tfrac{x}{2}})\right)\\
&= x \log 2 + O(\sqrt{x})
\end{align}

So indeed $$\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{F(x)-G(x)}{x} = \log 2$$

Comment: And the argument gives an error term, $(F(x)-G(x))/x=\log2+O(x^{-1/2})$.